# Filter a List based on words from String Array

Tags: java, list, collections, lambda, java-stream

I have a result set having `List<Employees>` sent by another application.

```
class Employee{
    Long id;
    String name;
    String gender;
    List<String> projects;
    // Getters
    // Setters
}
```

I need to write a method or lambda expression to filter the `List` using a bunch of query words (`String[]`) passed from the UI.

Any word in the `String[]` can match any variable (id, name, gender, projects). All List which have a match should be returned. part of name should also match e.g.: "john" should match List 1 and 3 in the example.

```
List<Employee> filter (empList, queryWords) {
    // code
}
```

Can you point me in the right direction to achive this?

```
example:

List:
1.  121, john doe   , male  , (proj1)
2.  125, sam    , female, (proj4 proj5 proj9)
3.  129, john lam   , male  , (proj1 proj2 proj5)
4.  143, peter pan  , male  , (proj4 proj8) 
5.  151, linda  , female, (proj8 proj7 proj3 proj11)


Search Query Words:

1.  "female" "proj3"- should return only No.5
2.      "proj5"     - should return only No.2 and 3
3.      "john"          - should return No.1 and 3
4.      "pan"           - should return No.4
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ryekayo Added an example

Comment: As your filter() method signature shows you have to build a new List of employees that match the criteria. So as you did it manually you have to walk through the list of employees, check for every one employee whether it matches the criteria and if so add it to the new list. Checking for criteria match means check every variable whether it contains one of the query words. In either solution all lists and arrays must be walked through with whatever code (your code, given code, lambda expressions, ...). It would be nice to see the code that you have so far to implement the filter functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Employee> filter(empList, queryWords){
    List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    // look at each employee in the list
    for(Employee employee : empList){

        // look at each query string
        for(String queryWord : queryWords){

        // if any of the employee fields matches the query word, 
        // add it to our list and move to next employee
        if(employee.name.equals(queryWord) ||
            employee.gender.equals(queryWord) ||
            employee.id.toString().equals(queryWord) ||
            isQueryInList(queryWord, employee.projects)) {
                // add it to your results
                result.add(employee);

                // quit looking at the rest of the queryWords, 
                // we found one, thats enough, move on to the next employee
                break; 
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private boolean IsQueryInList(String queryWord, List<String> items){
    //check each item in the list to see if it matches the queryWord
    for(String item : items){
        if(queryWord.equals(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //if we didn't find any item that matches, return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  how to match the querywords with the Lists - List<String> projects along with name,id,gender

Comment: Updated to include the project list. If any of these answers help, please upvote to show your appreciation :)

Comment: got it.Your suggestion worked for me.
I tried to upvote, i might need more reputation for my votes to be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Write a method

```
private boolean employeeMatchesWord(Employee employee, String word)
```

that returns true if at least one field of the employee matches the given word.

Then use

```
return empList.stream()
              .filter(employee -> Arrays.stream(queryWords)
                                        .anyMatch(word -> employeeMatchesWord(employee, word))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the query words array to a `Set`, create a `Set` of properties from all the employee's members, and use `retainAll` to determine which employees have at least one of the query words:

```
public static List<Employee> filter (List<Employee> empList, String[] queryWords) {
    Set<String> queryWordsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(queryWords));

    return empList.stream().filter(e -> {
        Set<String> properties = new HashSet<>(e.getProjects());
        properties.addAll
            (Arrays.asList(e.getId().toString(), e.getName(), e.getGender()));
        properties.retainAll(queryWordsSet);
        return !properties.isEmpty();
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

EDIT:
As JB Nizet commented, the `retainAll` can be elegantly replaced with an `anyMatch` expression:

```
public static List<Employee> filter (List<Employee> empList, String[] queryWords) {
    Set<String> queryWordsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(queryWords));

    return empList.stream().filter(e -> {
        Set<String> properties = new HashSet<>(e.getProjects());
        properties.addAll
            (Arrays.asList(e.getId().toString(), e.getName(), e.getGender()));
        return properties.stream().anyMatch(queryWordsSet::contains);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: You could use `return queryWordsSet.stream().anyMatch(w -> properties.contains(w));` rather than `retainingAll()`. It should be more efficient.

Comment: @JBNizet Nice improvement, thanks! To go one step further, you could use `contains` as a functional interface. I edited my answer to add this.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it's probably more efficient to iterate though the short list of keywords and call contains on the (probably) longer property set than the inverse. I edited my comment. But yes, using a method reference is cleaner.

Comment: @JBNizet If both of them are held in `HashSet`s, does it really matter which way you go?

Comment: Yes. Let's take an extreme case: 1,000,000 properties, and 1 keyword. Calling properties.contains(keyword) for each keyword is very fast, since there is only 1 keyword, and HashSet.contains is O(1). On the other hand, iterating through the 1,000,000 properties to check that it's contained in the set of 1 keyword is much longer.

Comment: @JBNizet gotcha. Thanks! Extreme examples always help illustrate a point.

Comment: @Mureinik if the Name is "firstName lastName"  and my queryword is "firstName" or part of first name. How to still match it(something like substring should also match)